# Hypergeometric distribution - using probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I had a question about the hypergeometric distribution. I know how it is derived: the number of ways to choose successes times the number of ways to choose failures divided by the total number of ways to choose a sample.

$$Pr(A = x) =\frac {{X \choose x}*{N-X \choose n-x}}{N \choose n} $$

However, I do not see physical probabilities being used in this distribution, this only takes into account the number of ways.

Eg: If I had a population of 6 red balls and 4 yellow balls. The probability of picking a 4 red and 1 yellow ball without replacement is?

The first ball would have a $\frac {6}{10}$ chance of being picked as red and the remainder yellow. The probabilities decrease as we pick more balls. These "decreasing" probabilities are taken into account in the formula for the hypergeometric distribution but I cannot seem to visualise it. Could someone show me how this is possible?

Comment: Inside binomial coefficients are factorials and factorials are literally multiplication of decreasing numbers

Comment: Could I see an example?

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$
In the direct multiplication method, you will need to multiply by $5$ as the yellow ball could be in any of the $5$ positions, hence $\frac 6{10}\frac 59\frac 48\frac 37\frac 46 \cdot  5$

To see its correspondence with the combinations approach,
$\binom 6 4  \binom 4 1 /\binom{10}5 = \frac{6!}{4!2!}\cdot4 \times \frac{5!5!}{10!}$

= $\dfrac{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot\cancel{2\cdot1}\cdot4}{\bcancel{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}\cdot\cancel{2\cdot1}}\times\dfrac{5\cdot\bcancel{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}\cdot \cancel {5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}}{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot\cancel{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}}$

Answer (score 0):

Define successes as the chance of drawing red balls and failures as the chance of drawing yellow balls.  The random variable A in your formula is the number of red balls drawn.  The entire distribution in your example is described by $P(A=0), P(A=1), P(A=2), … P(A=6)$. (And $P(X=k)= 0 for X  \notin {0, 1, 2, …,6}$))   If you have an urn with various colors of balls and want to figure out how many ways various colors can be drawn, that is a combinatorics problem. You can represent the probabilities by the combinations you are seeking divided by the total combinations possible.  The hypergeometric distribution is like that but it more narrowly defines what is a success and what is a failure.   In the formula you provided, the first nCr in the numerator is the successes A of red balls and the second nCr is the failures of yellow balls while the denominator is all possible combinations.